# Want to get value out of angular2 ngfor button loop from async call

Tags: for-loop, angular, asynchronous, observable

I have an async for loop from an observalble which is an object of an array. I want to know how can I get the value out of this array when the button is clicked?

The object of array is like this: { topics: [ "first choice", "second choice", "third choice" ] }

```
<button *ngFor = "let choice of (choices | async)?.Topics">
{{question}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button *ngFor = "let choice of (choices | async)?.Topics" 
    (click)="clickHandler(choice)">
```

Comment: This seems like it should work, but I keep getting undefined for choice

Comment: That's probably because `choices` doesn't return what you expect. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: NVM You're amazing and really quick. I found it out, simple mistake. Thank you so much